# Enum с константами

Tags: множества, const, java

Добрый день.

Не подскажите, можно ли создать enum, чтобы каждому перечислению множества соответствовала константа (которую можно вызвать).

Что-то типа (только с возможностью обращения к константе):

```
 enum Entity{
    TEXT{ public static final String REG_EXP_TEXT ="[a-wA-Wа-яА-я]"; },
    NUMBER{ public static final String REG_EXP_TEXT ="(?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+"; }
}
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам.

Comment: @nolik03, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
enum Entity {
    TEXT("[a-wA-Wа-яА-я]"),
    NUMBER("(?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+");

    public final String REG_EXP_TEXT;

    Entity(String regExp){
        this.REG_EXP_TEXT = regExp;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, в данном случае вам лучше использовать интерфейс.

```
public interface RegularExpressions {
    public static final String REG_EXP_TEXT ="[a-wA-Wа-яА-я]";
    public static final String REG_EXP_TEXT ="(?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+";
}
```

Смысл не поменяется, а читабельность кода будет лучше. Нет-нет, я не говорю, что это нереально, просто приседания в использовании натолкнут вас именно на замену Enum на Interface.

[как здесь](http://www.quizful.net/post/java_enums)

Comment: Вы, простите, о каком стандарте языка C говорите? Неужели в C появился `public`, `String`, `final`, `interface`?

Comment: @VladD снимаю шляпу. Виноват)

Comment: @VladD а причем здесь C?